# Android App With Server Interaction

Tags: android, sql-server, interface, web, push-notification

I am trying to write an app that will have a web interface for business owners who can select a specific Android mobile app user via querying a database and then have either the website or database(a little unsure about how this would work) push information to the queried user's phone to create a notification for them via the app.

I have never created an app like this and the connection between the website, the database, and the mobile app on a user's phone are all a mystery to me. I've searched the Android developer website and cannot find anything that will accurately explain how to do this, and have also Google'd the topic without much luck.

All I ask is for someone to point me in the right direction to place the pieces together, any information you can provide would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will almost certainly involve Google Cloud Messaging.

Implementing GCM will involve a server in which all devices are registered with a central service. So you are half way there once you have GCM implemented. Well perhaps more so, almost everything you mentioned is basically just GCM.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `PHP` programming to interact with the website.

Refer [`Android App interaction with Web`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159172/android-app-interaction-with-web)

and also

[`Android App Development and Web Server Interactions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122841/android-app-development-and-web-server-interactions)

These links will be useful.Good luck..